# Modifying bit string in python

Tags: python, string

Currently, i have a bit string represented as

```
current = "011"
```

and what I'm trying to do is  to create a new string based of the bit string above with the `1` at index 1 replaced with `011` which would give me:

```
new = "00111"
```

The problem I'm having is that when I use the replace function, it replaced all the `1` in the string including the one at index 2 which is not what I desired.

```
new = current.replace("1","011")
    = 0011011  #not what I wanted
```

Would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Limit the number of replace to 1 such as below:

```
new = current.replace("1","011", 1)
```

Comment: @ArnavBorborah : It is actually resulting by a `replace()` however, the logical of the solution was not provided into that duplicate.

Comment: I guess you could say that, but I personally feel that this doesn't really add any major value to the duplicate; IMO, this would have been better as a comment to supplement the dupe.